# Calling upon a defined function with users input

Tags: python

what do I do to prompt for an input by the user with the following function?

Can I use `user = input("please enter number")` in this function.

```
def Func(x):
    total = 0
    for i in range(x):
        total += i * (i-1)
    return total
```

so adding it to the function would be like

```
def Func(x):
    user = input("please enter number: ")
    x=user
    total = 0
    for i in range(x):
        total += i * (i-1)
    return total
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you define the function, you can subsequently invoke it:

```
Func(5)
```

Answer (score 2):

Call the function to invoke it.

```
Func(5)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def Func(x):
    total = 0
    for i in range(x):
        total += i * (i-1)
    return total

a=Func(5)
print(a)
```